# Re-format excel data using groupby and add blank lines to dataframe in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a long excel file of 60 minute count rainfall for the course of a year. I am looking to read-in the excel file, aggregate the rainfall values for total daily rainfall (`group.by` works well), and then put these values into a new dataframe where each day of the year is a separate line with `0` if there was no rain that day and the `Value` of total daily rainfall if it did rain. I've outlined the steps I'd take and my attempt at the code below. I am open to other suggestions if what I've attempted to code is crap. The first lines of the excel file look like this:

```
60 Minute Counts, []            
Time Stamp  Latitude    Longitude   Value ()
Dec 27 2015 01:30:00 AM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 25 2015 01:00:00 PM 0.297   36.900  0.51
Dec 25 2015 10:30:00 AM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 25 2015 07:30:00 AM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 25 2015 05:00:00 AM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 25 2015 04:30:00 AM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 17 2015 02:30:00 AM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 16 2015 02:30:00 PM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 16 2015 02:00:00 PM 0.297   36.900  0.76
Dec 16 2015 12:30:00 PM 0.297   36.900  0.25
Dec 16 2015 12:00:00 PM 0.297   36.900  0.76
Dec 16 2015 11:30:00 AM 0.297   36.900  5.08
Dec 16 2015 11:00:00 AM 0.297   36.900  0.51
Dec 15 2015 03:30:00 PM 0.297   36.900  0.25
```

I then need to read in the excel file, which I've played around with:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'filename.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['60 minute counts']
```

But I'm not sure how to read in lines 3+ for the actual values.

After defining the dataframe `df0` for the `Time Stamp` and `Value ()` columns, then I need to convert the `Time Stamp` into a format like YYYY-MM-DD, which could use the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df0["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df0["time"])
df0["day"] = df0['time'].map(lambda x: x.day)
df0["month"] = df0['time'].map(lambda x: x.month)
df0["year"] = df0['time'].map(lambda x: x.year)
```

Then I need to combine the 60 minute count rainfall to be total daily rainfall, by:

```
df1 = df0.groupby(['Value ()', 'day', 'month', 'year'], as_index=False).sum()
```

And ultimately I need to make the dataframe that has a row for each day of the year and then the total daily rainfall. It would look like this:

```
Date    Value
2015-12-31  0
2015-12-30  0
2015-12-29  0
2015-12-28  0
2015-12-27  0.25
2015-12-26  0
2015-12-25  1.52
2015-12-24  0
2015-12-23  0
2015-12-22  0
2015-12-21  0
2015-12-20  0
2015-12-19  0
2015-12-18  0
2015-12-17  0.25
2015-12-16  7.62
```

... and so on

Let me know if it's helpful to post the entire file and I can add a dropbox link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df0.index = pd.to_datetime(df0["Time Stamp"])

df1 = df0.resample('D')['Value ()'].sum().fillna(0).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Time Stamp  Value ()
0  2015-12-15      0.25
1  2015-12-16      7.61
2  2015-12-17      0.25
3  2015-12-18      0.00
4  2015-12-19      0.00
5  2015-12-20      0.00
6  2015-12-21      0.00
7  2015-12-22      0.00
8  2015-12-23      0.00
9  2015-12-24      0.00
10 2015-12-25      1.51
11 2015-12-26      0.00
12 2015-12-27      0.25
```

Or `groupby` with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df0.index = pd.to_datetime(df0["Time Stamp"])

df1 = df0.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['Value ()'].sum().fillna(0).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Time Stamp  Value ()
0  2015-12-15      0.25
1  2015-12-16      7.61
2  2015-12-17      0.25
3  2015-12-18      0.00
4  2015-12-19      0.00
5  2015-12-20      0.00
6  2015-12-21      0.00
7  2015-12-22      0.00
8  2015-12-23      0.00
9  2015-12-24      0.00
10 2015-12-25      1.51
11 2015-12-26      0.00
12 2015-12-27      0.25
```

And if necessary add [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = df0.resample('D')['Value ()'].sum().sort_index(ascending=False).fillna(0).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Time Stamp  Value ()
0  2015-12-27      0.25
1  2015-12-26      0.00
2  2015-12-25      1.51
3  2015-12-24      0.00
4  2015-12-23      0.00
5  2015-12-22      0.00
6  2015-12-21      0.00
7  2015-12-20      0.00
8  2015-12-19      0.00
9  2015-12-18      0.00
10 2015-12-17      0.25
11 2015-12-16      7.61
12 2015-12-15      0.25


df1 = df0.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['Value ()'].sum()
         .sort_index(ascending=False).fillna(0).reset_index()
print (df1)
   Time Stamp  Value ()
0  2015-12-27      0.25
1  2015-12-26      0.00
2  2015-12-25      1.51
3  2015-12-24      0.00
4  2015-12-23      0.00
5  2015-12-22      0.00
6  2015-12-21      0.00
7  2015-12-20      0.00
8  2015-12-19      0.00
9  2015-12-18      0.00
10 2015-12-17      0.25
11 2015-12-16      7.61
12 2015-12-15      0.25
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank youuuu. 100k ;)

Comment: Nice @jezrael :) Could you just comment on the best way to get the data from the tab '60 minute counts' in the excel file into a dataframe in python?

Comment: I think [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) is more standard way, so it can work nice.